# How to check if a public key matches with a private key?

Tags: java, keystore, public-key-encryption

I am using Java, and KeyStore.

I have a public key and private key pair in the KeyStore.

When I read a certificate, and get the public key from the certificate.

How do I know if the public key in the certificate matches with the private key in the key store?

Comment: Encrypt a well known piece of data with the public key, decrypt it with the private and see if they match.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a public key and private key pair in the KeyStore.
>
> How do I know if the public key in the certificate matches with the private key in the key store?

Since the Keystore contains *pairs*, you look for the *pair* that has the same public key as the certificate.

Of course that is just the first step.  Next you (or more likely, the PKI library) needs to use the private key to check the certificate's signature.